# jquery: getting child element on click event

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a little solution for our SharePoint-Intranet. Therefor I need a typical FAQ-Webpart like

> Question 1
>
> Answer 1
>
> Question 2
>
> Answert 2

and so on.

I want the answer to toggle by clicking the question. Per default, all answers are hidden, and when I click one question, the answer to this question shows up.

But it don't work.

My Code looks like this:

```
<div class="faqWebpartWrapper">
    <div class="faqContainer">
        <a class="faqFrage" href="#">Question 1</a><br />
        <span class="faqAntwort">Answer 1</span>
    </div>
     <div class="faqContainer">
         <a class="faqFrage" href="#">Question 2</a><br />
        <span class="faqAntwort">Answer 2</span>
    </div>
</div>

$(".faqAntwort").hide();

$(".faqContainer").on("click", ".faqFrage", function(event) {
    console.log("clicked");   
    $(this).find(".faqAntwort").show();
});
```

Here is a link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TJ22g/

I think the solution to my problem is pretty simple, but I'm not quite familiar to jquery (so far!), so I would be grateful if anyone could give me a tip.

Thank you!

Comment: add a display:none style to .faqAntwort so they are inittaly not shown  and not erst wenn the js is executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.faqAntwort` is no a child of `.faqFrage`, its a sibling. You can use one of these methods.

Use

```
 $(this).parent().find(".faqAntwort").show();
```

*OR*

```
 $(this).closest('.faqContainer').find(".faqAntwort").show();
```

*OR*

```
 $(this).siblings('.faqAntwort').show();
```

Comment: Ahhhh okay... so "this" does not reference to the selector of the "on"-method but to the actually triggered element. That was my mistake. Thank you guys, now its working!

Comment: @user3219729, You are using delegate event approach, so `this` refers to `faqFrage`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** since `.faqAntwort` span is the sibling of clicked `.faqFrage` anchor:

```
$(".faqAntwort").hide();

$(".faqContainer").on("click", ".faqFrage", function(event) {
    console.log("clicked");   
    $(this).siblings('.faqAntwort').show();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ22g/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method as it is the next sibling:

```
$(this).next(".faqAntwort").show();
```

Comment: `.next()` will not work because next sibling of clicked `.faqFrage` is a `<br />` element

Answer (score 0):

You may use closest() like  `$(this).closest('.faqContainer').find(".faqAntwort").show();`